# Face Images and Face Databases

Tags: images, database, web-development, image-processing, search-engine

I want to get face photos or images of a given race e.g. asians from search engines like google.com or bing.com for a photo profiling software project I am building. What would be the best search text or string that I would issue to a search engine to get face photos in their thousands? Is there a research database instead that is available for downloading photos or images e.g. categorized by race e.g asians database, africans etc?

I will gladly appreciate your help and suggestions on this.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). If you're looking for data, our sister-site [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be worth checking with.

Comment: Apologies @Izzy for that and thanks for recommending Open Data. I have since transferred this Question [there](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/face-images-and-face-databases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another answer to the question as my first answer wasn't right, due to my misunderstanding. I will let the first answer there just in case of someone else looks for something like that I've mentioned in my post before.

Back to the Question itself.
I found a [good overview](http://www.face-rec.org/databases/) over many different databases in the net. Maybe you want to take a look at it.

Maybe the **BU-3DFE Database** would be something for you.

> The database contains 100 subjects (56% female, 44% male), ranging age from 18 years to 70 years old, with a variety of ethnic/racial ancestries, including White, Black, East-Asian, Middle-east Asian, Indian, and Hispanic Latino.

The database isn't just for one ethical group but it should be easy to split it into the groups and run your tests on it.

Hopefully this will help you more. :-)

Comment: Thank you @Ionic That's a great collection of facial recognition databases compiled there. I will see to it that I make contact with Dr. Lijun Yin so that they grant me access to that database I carry out tests with it.

Comment: Nice to help you with that. Hopefully you had successful tests. Btw. Really interesting project at all. I like techniques like that. :-)

Comment: I will have to first get that Database then I group races together then use that to train models for gender, age and emotion classification. At the moment I am pre-occupied with doing gender classification for blacks then later on I will do age and emotion subsequently. I had to learn how to do face processing first. Thanks for your help and pointing me to those databases. I am sure I will use some of them to do more various classifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [FaceAPI from Microsoft AzureML](http://gallery.azureml.net/MachineLearningAPI/b0b2598aa46c4f44a08af8891e415cc7). It provides information like age, gender, etc.

Another good API can be found [here](http://animetrics.com/). It's from Animetrics.

Both need your development. As your question is a bit unclear I just can provide this libraries due to your question. :-)

Hopefully there is one Library for you. :-)

Comment: @Iconic thank you for your input. My objective is to have a single race only database e.g. Asians only database for training an Asian face recognition model or an Africans only database only for training an African face recognition model. I want to improve my test results for my targeted race in my test recognition results.

Comment: Ah ok. well in this case this answer won't help you. I'll going to delete it later :)

Comment: It doesn't hurt anyone if it stays. It may be the last resort for a lost soul who gets directed here from a search engine lookup. Thank you for your willingness to help.